# launch only remotely installed package on remote machine

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the following setup:

- a computer where the roscore runs
- a remote computer, where a certain node named zed_ros_wrapper ( the node to read out images of the ZED stereo camera) should run

I would like to launch the whole system with a launch file on the computer where the roscore runs.

When I try to launch the zed_ros_wrapper node remotely, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
p.start()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
self._start_infrastructure()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
self._load_config()
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 746, in load
self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 718, in _load_launch
self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 662, in _recurse_load
self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 256, in _param_tag
vals = self.opt_attrs(tag, context, ('value', 'textfile', 'binfile', 'command'))
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 202, in opt_attrs
return [self.resolve_args(tag_value(tag,a), context) for a in attrs]
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 370, in resolve_args
resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 383, in _resolve_args
resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 151, in _find
source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 197, in _find_executable
full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
ResourceNotFound: zed_wrapper
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ubuntu/git_catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/camera_calibration

[... the entire ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ... ]

ROS path [37]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS path [38]=/home/ubuntu/git_catkin_ws/src/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS
```

Something to mention is maybe that the zed_wrapper_node is installed on the remote machine, but not on the machine running the roscore. This is due to the fact that the compilation of the zed_wrapper_node needs the CUDA 8.0 libraries which do not run on the machine running the roscore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264899/launch-only-remotely-installed-package-on-remote-machine/) by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered, that apparently the package zed_ros_wrapper needs to be detectable also on the host machine in order to be launched on the remote machine. I don't know why this is, but as soon as I compiled a dummy package also called zed_ros_wrapper on the host machine, the error would disappear and the node would launch without problems on the remote machine.

So as a general rule, to be launched on a remote computer, packages need also to be installed (or at least a package of the same name should be detectable) on the host computer from which the node is remotely launched. Does anybody know of a hint in the ROS documentation about this?

---

Originally posted by [sihe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30331/sihe/) with karma: 60 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-10**:
This hack doesn't seem to work anymore... unfortunately...

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-10**:
See my workaround [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/371480/roslaunch-nodes-launch-files-only-available-on-remote-machine/?answer=371491#post-id-371491)